# how to make a custom kernel which boots a custom initrd.img file

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, initrd

I was mining information on "how to create a kernel" and have created a simple kernel which just prints "my first kernel". Later, I went on to creating a small initrd.img file which launches a "busybox ash -login" command. Now, my question is, how to make the kernel use the initrd.img file to boot into a shell [the $ screen] ??

I am trying to create my own Linux Distribution and so I am trying to understand the basics

I do know my task does not require an initrd but I am curious that's all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-arm-and-emulate-with-qemu/). Here exactly your requirement is explained where it prints `hello world` at the boot by creating `initrd image`.